# HTML Email with several tables has tiny white border between the tables in print version

Tags: html, email, printing

I am working on a HTML email newsletter. Because of the given design I used several tables (with sliced background images inside the TD's). Everything works well, but in printout there are tiny white horizontal lines just where the tables outlines are.
Rendering in browsers and E-Mail Clients itself is ok; no borders, no margins, everything renders gapless.
Those lines appear however in Firefox's print preview for example or in the actual hardcopy;

My client is very picky about a perfect print layout.

Does anybody know where those lines come from and how to get rid of them?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating html emails is even tougher than developing for old browsers. There are tons of limitations to look out for. Never sell a perfect looking html email newsletter unless you're 100% sure it's possible. The same goes for printing as well because you have little control of the printer output.

You're using background images and **background images are by default not printed out**. Perhaps this is what's **causing the lines to suddenly appear while printing**. You could try using a print css to remove those lines but remember to include all your css inline for the email newsletter. You can find some more tips on sites like http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Just came back to this one and iirc the solution had to do with setting the images to display:block.